# Log4J2 JDBC Appender Unable to write to database

Tags: java, jdbc, log4j2, appender

I have the following appender for log4J2 but I get the Error "Unable to write to database":

```
 <JDBC name="Audit" tableName="audittestlogs">
  <DriverManager connectionString="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/powerobjectordb" 
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        username="sa" 
        password="mysql" />
  <Column name="Username" pattern="%level" />
  <Column name="Eventname" pattern="%logger" />
  <Column name="Reason" pattern="%message" />
</JDBC>
```

Do I have to establish a connection separately or what could be the problem with this appender? I am calling it in the standard  logging way:

```
logger.debug("Test");
```

But it does give me this error message:

```
2021-08-23 15:41:00,936 AWT-EventQueue-0 ERROR Unable to write to database [JdbcManager{name=Audit, bufferSize=0, tableName=audittestlogs, columnConfigs=[{ name=Username, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Eventname, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Reason, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]}] for appender [Audit]. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.AppenderLoggingException: Error writing to JDBC Manager 'JdbcManager{name=Audit, bufferSize=0, tableName=audittestlogs, columnConfigs=[{ name=Username, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Eventname, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Reason, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]}': JDBC connection not available [columnConfigs=[{ name=Username, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Eventname, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Reason, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }], sqlStatement=insert into audittestlogs (Username,Eventname,Reason) values (?,?,?), factoryData=FactoryData [connectionSource=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/powerobjectordb, tableName=audittestlogs, columnConfigs=[{ name=Username, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Eventname, layout=%logger, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=Reason, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[], immediateFail=false, retry=true, reconnectIntervalMillis=5000, truncateStrings=true], connection=null, statement=null, reconnector=Reconnector [latch=java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch@2ae39358[Count = 0], shutdown=false], isBatchSupported=false, columnMetaData=null]
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.checkConnection(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:507)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.connectAndStart(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:610)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeThrough(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:888)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:264)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:110)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:156)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:129)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:120)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:84)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:540)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:498)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:481)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:456)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2017)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1983)
at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.fatal(AbstractLogger.java:1053)
at fensteraudit.AuditWindow$10.actionPerformed(AuditWindow.java:267)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1972)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2313)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6617)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6382)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2264)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4993)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2322)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4934)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4563)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4504)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2308)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2773)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4825)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

I hope someone can help me.

Greetings
Alex

Comment: Can you connect via mysql *on that same host* with those credentials?

Comment: Yes, I can. I can connect via MySQL Workbench as well as via "regular" JDBC connection.

Comment: Just checking ;) And I meant you open mysql on the same machine as the java is running. Unfortunately i've never used a JDBC appender so can't help further